# Tom Dieck Lemma 3.2.3

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$\newcommand{\U}{\mathfrak{U}}$
$\newcommand{\I}{[\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}]}$
Tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology* has the following Lemma (3.2.3)

> Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be an open covering of $B \times [0,1]$, for each $b \in B$ there exists an open neighborhood $V(b)$ of $b$ in $B$ and $n = n(b) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $0 \leq i \leq n$ the set $V(b) \times \I$ is contained in some element of $\U$

He does not prove this Lemma so I thought I might as well prove it as an exercise. Could you review my attempt?

$\newcommand{\B}{B \times [0,1]}$
The open sets are open subset of the form $$A \subset B \times [x,y]
\subset [0,1] \ \text{and}\ 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$$
The elements of $\U$ also have to be of this type. (I believe this statement or its implications can have counterexamples)

So by definition, if $\U$ covers $\B$ then there is a $U \in \U$ such that $V(b) \subseteq U$ and since $U$ is of the type $V(b) \times [x,y]$, and then we argue $[x,y]$ is of the form $\I$ elsewise we have a counterexample in the general case

---

I know this isn't really even an attempt it's more of a mess.....
Can anyone help to somehow clear this mess and/or provide some hints towards the proof?

---

**Edit(1)**
Or maybe......

Fix a $V(b)$ and notice that a cover of $V(b)$, $U \subset \U$ can be written as $X \times \bigcup \I$ for $X$ being the restriction of $f: B \rightarrow \U$ at $V(b)$ (that is $X = f(V(b)))$
Now since it is a union of $\I$ we can adjust the $n$ and $i$ as per our liking I haven't tried this but I guess it could work.

---

Comment: Probably $\overline{f}: \mathfrak{U} \rightarrow B$ ($X = \overline{f^{-1}}(V(b))$ could've be better in Edit(1)

Comment: For every $t\in [0,1]$ there is an open neighborhood $U(t)\in\mathfrak{U}$ of $(b,t)$. By definition of the product topology, there is a neighborhood $V(t)$ of $b$ and $\epsilon(t) >0$ such that $V(t)\times(t-\epsilon(t),t+\epsilon(t))\subset U(t)$. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: @VincentBoelens unfortunately no, I don't get what is $\epsilon(t)$

Comment: By definition of the product topology there is a neighborhood $V(t)$ of $b$ and a neighborhood $I(t)$ of $t$ such that $V(t)\times I(t)\subset U(t)$. It is not strictly necessary, but if you want, by definition of the topology on $[0,1]$ you can find $\epsilon(t)>0$ depending on $t$ such that the open interval $(t-\epsilon(t),t+\epsilon(t))$ is contained in $I(t)$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I think that's what I have tried to do in my question except it's written in a very weird way...?

Comment: Wait what the duck have I written?

Comment: To be honest I can't really make sense of what you have written. You should probably review the definition of the product topology. If you understand what I wrote above then you are almost done using compactness of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens even I can't understand what I had written and yes I did understand your comment and reached the conclusion I think my attempt (here) needs more revising... and now I feel stupid about how I had possibly missed such a trivial thing